# How to search/isearch just comments?

Tags: search, isearch, comment

Is it possible to perform a `search/isearch` just in comment regions of the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use library [**Isearch+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus), specifically file [**`isearch-prop.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch-prop.el).

As it says [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus#isearchp-thing):

> You can search the text of THINGS of various kind (sexps, lists, defuns, lines, pages, sentences, filenames, strings, ***comments***, xml/html elements, symbols,…), using command `isearchp-thing`. This is equivalent to using command `isearchp-thing-define-contexts`, which marks such zones with a text property, and then using `isearchp-property-forward`.

Also:

> You can hide or show code comments during Isearch, using `M-;` (command `isearchp-toggle-hiding-comments`). You can toggle ignoring comments during Isearch, using `C-M-;` (command `isearchp-toggle-ignoring-comments`).

And the doc string of command `isearchp-thing` says this, which is pertinent for searching comments:

> If user option `isearchp-ignore-comments-flag` is nil then include
>   THINGs located within comments.  Non-nil (the default value) means to
>   ignore things inside comments for searching.  In particular, this
>   means that *for `comment` as THING search contexts, be sure to turn off
>   ignoring of comments*.  You can toggle whether comments are ignored
>   using `C-M-;` during Isearch, but to see the effect you will need to
>   invoke Isearch again.

---

**UPDATE after your comment that you got an infinite loop:**

The cause of the looping is [*Emacs bug #9300*](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=9300), which still has not been fixed.  I thought it would be fixed by Emacs 24, so I had a test in the code that does the right thing if the Emacs version is 24 or later, and otherwise does the workaround thing. Unfortunately, if you use the bugged vanilla Emacs version of function `bounds-of-thing-at-point` then you can have only the workaround, which is less than ideal. Anyway, the latest version of `isearch-prop.el` treats all Emacs versions as bugged, giving you the workaround.

The right thing to do is, as suggested in the `isearch-prop.el` file header, to use library [**Thing At Point +**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ThingAtPointPlus) ([**`thingatpt+.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/thingatpt%2b.el)). It does not have the bug, and it gives you better thing-at-point behavior all around.

Library `isearch-prop.el` does not strictly require library `thingatpt+.el`, but I highly recommend using both.

(It took me a while to re-debug this, as I had forgotten about the Emacs bug, and the fact that the code made the assumption that the bug would be fixed by Emacs 24. I don't usually do that kind of thing, but as the bug report points out the needed (and trivial) fix, I figured that it would soon be fixed.)

Comment: Thanks, I installed this package. After `M-x isearchp-this` I answered the query `Thing (type)` by `comment`and it was accepted. Then it is asked `Predicate to filter search contexts:` I answered by `isearch-forward`. The comments became invisible and I can search within non-comment regions. I asked the opposite. What option I should select in the query `Thing (type)` in order that only comments remain visible?

Comment: I updated the answer with a mention that you need to turn off ignoring of comments when you want to search only comments. I also clarified this in the doc string of `isearchp-thing`, in the library. Thx. Also, just answer with the default value of `nil` to the prompt for a predicate (i.e., just hit `RET` without typing any input) - no predicate is needed here.

Comment: Let me report that when I hit `RET` to the prompt for a predicate, emacs get completely frozen (Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2015-04-11 on LEG570).

Comment: OK, thanks for the report. Please try the [latest version](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch-prop.el), which fixes this. I edited the post to explain more about this. The problem is [Emacs bug #9300](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=9300), which still has not been fixed (or even responded to).

Comment: Did you set `isearchp-ignore-comments-flag` to `nil`? You can use `M-x set-variable` to do that, or you can use `C-M-;` during Isearch to toggle it (but restart Isearch for the change to take effect). This is explained in the answer and in the doc in file `isearch-prop.el` and on the [Isearch+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus#isearchp-toggle-ignoring-comments) page.

Comment: Sorry, it works I had forgotten to set  set isearchp-ignore-comments-flag to nil. Now it perfectly works.

Comment: This was kind of a gotcha. I've updated the command now so that if you pick `comment` as the THING, and you are not searching the complement (i.e., non-comments), and `isearchp-ignore-comments-flag` is non-`nil`, then that option is automatically set to `nil` (and a message tells you this). Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Using a library with this feature as @Drew suggested is probably the best way to go.

Otherwise -- depending on the comment syntax -- you might be able to use `isearch-forward-regex` and search using a regular expression that includes leading comment characters. For example in lisp you could do a regex search for `;.*foo` to find lines that include "foo" in a comment.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion to use regex is a partial answer. For using the libraries `isearch+/isearch-prop` I cannot yet figure out how to answer the query `Predicate to filter search contexts:` for obtaining the answer to my specific question.

Comment: @Name: See my reply. Should be OK now.